# Numerical optimisation method for a function that is slow to compute but quick to compare

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I wish to fine-tune a numerical optimization algorithm in a particular problem where the criterion is very slow to compute exactly but can quickly return true/false of whether the exact result will be below/above a particular value. In a sense, the function is much faster to compare than to compute. What optimization algorithms would be able to utilize this feature, i.e., be able to rely on results of comparison operations, at least in some points?

[Nelder-Mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) is one of such methods that comes to mind, but are there others?

Comment: Do you mean that evaluating the objective function $f$ at some $x$ is computationally expensive but deciding, say, $f (x) > 0$ is cheap?

Comment: Exactly. It is significantly cheaper, at least.

Comment: What kind of problem?  What kind of objective function?  With equality constraints? Inequality constraints?  Over the reals? Or over the integers?  Details, please.

Comment: It's a complicated statistical criterion function. Assume it's over reals, smooth and continuous. I don't expect an exact answer, but a direction for further research.